# How do I make sure that Iron-Router's before function runs?

Tags: meteor, rendering, iron-router

I am using Iron-Router with Meteor. When the user goes to /foo/:routeID, it's important that the foo is loaded before they arrive. Sometimes it doesn't get loaded in time though and the page will render wonky. I haven't been able to figure out a discernible pattern to when these times occur.

If I change it such that the page re-renders after the foo is loaded, then there's a noticeable update. I'd rather just have it s.t. the page renders when the foo object is loaded. How do I make this so? My current routing is below.

```
this.route('foo', {
    path:'/foo/:routeID',
    layoutTemplate:'base',
    before: function() {
        foo = Foos.findOne({routeID:this.params.routeID});
        console.log('before');
        console.log(foo);
        Session.set('foo', foo);
    }
```

Comment: You should definitely read this part of the Iron Router documentation : https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-wait

Comment: Was going to say the same thing as saimeunt. Make sure that you subscribe to foo and call .wait on it. Also make sure you have a loading template defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using IronRouter, Before will always run, but it won't always block, so if something takes a while, your other code could still end up running too early.

In order to make sure that your collection is loaded, you need to call .wait() on it to force Meteor/IronRouter to not try to display the template or run other relevant code until after the collection has loaded.

Something like this should work:

```
this.route('foo', {
path:'/foo/:routeID',
layoutTemplate:'base',
before: function() {
    this.subscribe('foos').wait();
    foo = Foos.findOne({routeID:this.params.routeID});
    console.log('before');
    console.log(foo);
    Session.set('foo', foo);
}
```

You will need to make sure that you have a [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) function defined as well (and turn off autopublish if you haven't yet) for foo.

**EDIT:**
Additionally, for security and to prevent all users/routes from downloading every Foo and then filtering on the client side you can use a publish/subscribe function with a param to make sure you aren't downloading the **entire** collection each time you hit a page.

```
this.subscribe('foos', this.params.routeID).wait();
```

Comment: It's in the publish function that security can be done.